# if else statement won't pick up empty cell vs. cell with value

Tags: javascript

```
function gamEmail(e) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var first = sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("First Name")).getValues()[0];
  var nickName = sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Preferred Name")).getValues()[0];

    if (nickName.isBlank() == true)
       {var name = first;}

       else
         {name = nickName;}

  var last = sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Last Name")).getValues()[0];
  var mobile = sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Mobile Phone")).getValues()[0];
  var office = sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Office")).getValues()[0];

var subject = "**GAM New User**" + " " + name + " " + last;
```

this script sets up a GAM command line for new users, the name variable needs to be the new users first name unless they have a nickName. Then I need to set the name variable to nickName. I can't seem to find an answer. Any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the `isBlank` method look like?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isBlank()

Comment: isBlank()  

Returns true if the range is totally blank.  

 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  
 var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D4");  

 Logger.log(range.isBlank());

Comment: OK, well if something returns either `true` or `false` you should change the condition to simply `if (nickName.isBlank())`. It looks like one of your variables is not being assigned the value you expect. I suggest that you check through them all one by one and see if you spot anything unexpected.

Comment: Typically it's seen as good coding style in JS to declare your variables at the top of the function, so it might make things clearer if you declare `var name;` before your `if..else`. You could even turn the whole thing into one line: `var name = nickName.isBlank() ? first : nickName;`. However, I don't think that this is your problem.

Comment: I've been playing around with it. And I took out the nickName.isBlank and changed it to `sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Preferred Name")).getValues()[0].isBlank` because I believe the isBlank method is trying to find a cell not a variable. The script will send the email, however the name comes back undefined

Comment: thanks tom for the help, this ended up working out `var name;  
     if (nickName == "")
        {name = first;}
      else 
       {name = nickName;}`

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted! By the way, that code could be reduced to `var name = nickName.trim() === "" ? first : nickName;`. It's a good idea to trim the `nickName` in case it only contains spaces.